# „benutzen“ versus „benützen“ in Heinrich Bölls Übersetzung von „Der Fänger im Roggen“

Tags: spelling, grammaticality, literature, book, reformed-orthography

Gerade eben lese ich [Heinrich Bölls](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_B%C3%B6ll) Übersetzung von [Jerome David Salingers](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._D._Salinger) berühmtem Buch [„Der Fänger im Roggen“](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_F%C3%A4nger_im_Roggen). In Kapitel 4 ist mir dabei eine sehr seltsame Formulierung aufgefallen. Ganz zu Beginn heißt es dort:

*Der Wand entlang befinden sich ungefähr zehn Waschbecken nebeneinander. Stradlater **benützte** das in der Mitte.*

Nun habe ich einmal im Internet nachgesehen, aber „benützte“ statt „benutzte“ ist mir dort nicht untergekommen. Es kommt mir so falsch vor, wie wenn jemand sagt, dass „Person XY mich frägt, ob …“, als ob es das Wort „frägen“ gäbe.

Hat der Literaturnobelpreisträger hier also einen Übersetzungsfehler begangen?

Comment: Ein Blick in den [_Duden_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/benutzen) erleichtert die Antwortfindung: Es hängt von der Region ab.

Comment: Heinrich Böll war Rheinländer. Nun ja, dann hat er eben diese Variante benutzt. Ich habe nur auf die Schnelle nichts dazu gefunden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nein, es handelt sich wohl nicht um einen Übersetzungsfehler.
*Benützen* ist lediglich kaum gebräuchlich in großen Teilen Deutschlands; in Teilen von Süddeutschland, der Schweiz und Österreich aber schon. [Diese Karte](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f03b/) zeigt die regionalen Unterschiede.

Und anscheinend ist [Kreuzau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreuzau) – der Todesort von Heinrich Böll – einer der Orte, in denen *benützen* benützt wird.

Comment: Scheint eine seltsame Exklave in Nordrhein-Westfahlen zu sein. Ich komme aus der „brauchen/benutzen“-Exklave in Bayern. ;-)

Comment: Dann ist aber immer noch die Frage, ob Böll in dem Buch mehrfach Regionalismen verwendet, was auf ein Stilmittel hindeuten würde, oder nicht, was auf einen Fehler hindeutet.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=benützen%2F%28benutzen%2Bbenützen%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28benützen%20/%20%28benutzen%20%2B%20benützen%29%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user unknown: Beide Wörter sind Standard, und beide Wörter werden in unterschiedlichen Regionen verwendet. Von einem Regionalismus kann man jeweilen nur aus Sicht der anderen Region sprechen, und von einem Fehler kann so oder so keine Rede sein.

Comment: “scheinbar“ sollte hier “anscheinend“ sein (in Kreuzau ist es wirklich so, nicht nur zum Schein.)