# German equivalent of the phrase "poetic licence"

Tags: phrase, phrase-request

In English there is a phrase, "poetic licence". This means that the author's statement is not strictly true, but has been exaggerated or embroidered a little for the sake of dramatic effect. A similar term is "artistic licence".

For example, the English sentence "The filmmakers used a bit too much artistic licence" (i.e. they deviated a bit too far from the original storyline).

I tried translating it directly, to something like "Die Filmemacher benützten künstlerische Lizenz" (or "poetische Lizenz") but is there a more idiomatic translation?

Comment: Direct translation is appropriate here but you chose the wrong translation for “license”; in English the word has several meanings but not all of those are translatable as “Lizenz” in German.

Comment: Note the regional difference in usage between _benützen_ and _benutzen_. Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38554

Comment: [Leo](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/poetic%20license) has a prepackaged answer, so I vote for closing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think "poetic license" and "artistic license" are best translated as "dichterische Freiheit" and "künstlerische Freiheit". Those phrases literally mean "poetic liberty" and "artistic liberty" and are fairly common in German to express what you referred to in your first paragraph.

---

Some possible translations for

> The filmmakers used a bit too much artistic licence

are

> Die Filmemacher haben etwas zu sehr von ihrer künstlerischen Freiheit Gebrauch gemacht

or

> Die Filmemacher haben sich ein bisschen zu viele künstlerische Freiheiten genommen.

Comment: Since one literal translation of “license” is in fact “Freiheit”, “dichterische/künstlerische Freiheit” are literally translated as “poetic/artistic license”, no need to change the English wording to get a literal translation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I disagree. Can you please give a few examples? 'Licence' might in some restricted meaning or in a figurative sense be used as a translation for 'Freiheit', but I doubt as a general or literal translation.

Comment: @jarnbjo [definition, noun, meaning 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+license&oq=define+license); there’s not really room for interpretation. It’s its literal meaning, and its original etymology (although I’m the first to clamour that etymology ≠ contemporary meaning).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: `Künstlerische Freiheit` is the right translation for `licentia poetica`/`artistic license`. The original etymology of `license` is not the same as `Freiheit`, though. `Freiheit` is a possible translation for Latin `licentia`, but `licentia` has moral connotations that `Freiheit` does not have, e.g., `Zügellosigkeit` or `Willkür`. If you translate a German text to Latin, you would rarely choose `licentia` for `Freiheit`.

Comment: @Frank I agree with all these things but I don’t understand how they pertain to the discussion. *One* literal translation of “license” is “Freiheit”, and it is exactly the right one in this context. Both “license” and “Freiheit” have multiple distinct meanings (many if not most words do), and their primary meanings differ. But the sets of their meanings overlap, and the overlap happens exactly where we need it.

Comment: @Konrad: My concern is about "its original etymology". The etymology of *licence* is not the same as that of *Freiheit*, even if their meaning overlaps. The etymology of *libertas* (which might have evolved similarly to *Freiheit*) and *licentia* is not the same, even though both words mean *freedom*.

Comment: @Frank Ah that’s a misunderstanding: I didn’t intend to claim that the etymology of the two words was the same, merely that the Latin origin of “license” already had the same meaning, which is translatable as “Freiheit”.

Comment: Another way of putting @Konrad's point is that one meaning of "license" is, to quote Merriam-Webster, "freedom of action" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/license). That is the meaning of "license" being used in that expression. When you do a word-for-word translation, sometimes you have to pick a different word in language B depending on which meaning is being used for the word in language A. This is one of those cases.

Answer (score 16):

The idiom is "künstlerische Freiheit(en)", like this:

> Die Filmemacher haben sich die künstlerische Freiheit genommen, die Handlung zu verändern. (neutral)
>
> Die Filmemacher haben sich etwas zu viele künstlerische Freiheiten erlaubt. (negativ)

Answer (score 14):

The German equivalents to this phrase are usually

> "dichterische Freiheit" and
>   "künstlerische Freiheit" resp.

So the example would be "Die Filmemacher nutzten die künstlerische Freiheit …".